# How to mount exFAT drive on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, external-hdd, exfat

I'm trying to mount the drive but it just keeps returning this:

```
sophie@sophie-zen:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
mount: /mnt/sda2: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist.
```

I have so far installed exfat-fuse and exfatprogs despite my linux kernel supporting exFAT natively, but to no avail. The drive works in Windows just fine and shows up in the Ubuntu Disks manager, but as unallocated space. I also ran chkdsk on the drive in windows and testdisk in Ubuntu and they found no errors. What am I missing?

---

Edit:

Output of "sudo fdisk -l":

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: 1TB             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9A1E2DFB-F3D0-45A5-9C36-7E4F006B213E

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 1953525127 1953260936 931,4G Microsoft basic data
```

/mnt only has the two folders I created and /media is empty. Fast startup is also disabled, along with fast boot, and the drive in question is removable so I doubt hibernation files are the cause of the issue.

---

Edit 2: I formatted a random pendrive as exFAT and it reads fine, so something about my other drive is making it not work.

Comment: You have the wrong mountpoint I would expect a windows partition to be mounted in /media/ by default and using either a volume name or the UUID. Check /etc/fstab if it is in there otherwise use Nautilus/Nemo to click on the mount and check the mountpoint (properties or command line using something like fdisk -l or df -H)

Comment: In addition, check that Windows fast start up has not set hibernation flag. Linux drivers do not mount hibernated Windows partitions as read/write to prevent data loss. Restore of hibernation would lose any written data. You may be able to manually mount read only. Discusses NTFS, but applies to all Windows: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @Rinzwind It's an external SSD and I checked both /media and /mnt before trying anything. The drive doesn't show up in the GUI file manager, or /etc/fstab, but shows up if I type "sudo fdisk -l" as "/dev/sda1" as a "Microsoft reserved" and "/dev/sda2" as "Microsoft basic data"

Comment: @oldfred Windows fast start up and uefi fast boot is disabled and it still shows up as either unallocated space in fdisk or not at all in the file explorer.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Did you create mount point /mnt/sda2? Generally not good idea to use FAT32 or exFAT for larger partitions. NTFS would probably be better if you want to use with both Windows & Linux. The standard exFAT implementation is not journaled and only uses a single file allocation table and free space map. 
But exFAT will store larger files than FAT32. But still should not be used for larger partitions as chkdsk may take forever. 
And it does not have Linux ownership & permissions.

Comment: @oldfred The external drive I bought came with exFAT preformatted so I used it without issues so far, but I might just buy a sata SSD and copy the data across and reformat if I can't figure out how to make exFAT work.